Not able to start a spark session in Jupyter notebook
When I am trying to build a spark session in python, its taking a lot of time and nothing happens, nor it throws the error.
I have waited for almost an hour and it was still in progress.

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder\
.appName("MyProcess")\
.master("local")\
.getOrCreate()

Can someone please check what's wrong here?

here are the steps and sample-data.txt contains some random text and I did in jupyter notebook of anaconda. u can try it in jupyter notebook or in cloud and this code snippet from Data Analysis with Python and PySpark book by Jonathan Rioux
!pip install pyspark

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Analyzing data").getOrCreate()

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Analyzing data").getOrCreate()

book = spark.read.text(r'C:\Users\KAKOLLKE\pyspark\sample-data.txt')

book.show()

here is output
+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|The Project Guten...|
|                    |
|This eBook is for...|
|almost no restric...|
|re-use it under t...|
|with this eBook o...|

